# Fixed amout of page links in pagination

Tags: ee2, pagination

So I have a blog where I am paginating my entries to 6 per page. Generally the standard pagination built into EE is fine, but for this I only ever want 4 page numbers to show in the pagination bar like so

Prev 1 2 3 4 Next *or* Prev 7 8 9 10 Next

I don't think that the `page_padding` parameter will work in this way - do you know if it's possible to have EE's pagination work in this way or will I have to get an add on like [AB Pagination](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ab-pagination)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I got the AB Pagination plugin after all - not only do I think that standard pagination won't work for this, but there are other things we need to do that AB Pagination solves, so there we have it!